# How to import libusb dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and have troubles using libusb dll. I have downloaded their source and compiled the dll version under **release**. New folder was created: **D:\libusb-1.0.9\Win32\Release\dll** which contains the .lib and .dll files. The next thing I did, was copied the .dll to my Visual studio projects folder, where the source files reside.

In Visual studio I then did: **project->properties->linker->input->additional dependencies** and pasted in the path to .lib file: **D:\libusb-1.0.9\Win32\Release\dll\libusb-1.0.lib**. Then I did **project->properties->linker->general->additional library directories** and pasted in the folder where the libusb header files are: **D:\libusb-1.0.9\libusb**.

Then I tried including the `#include "libusb.h"` but it says it cant find the file.

What else do I need to do, to make it work...?

**EDIT:**

These are the exact errors:

- Cannot open include file: 'libusb.h': No such file or directory
- IntelliSense: cannot open source file "libusb.h"

Comment: Add the folder containing libusb.h to the additional include directories. In the c++ settings.

Comment: @user1806687 Just add .lib file under MSVC 2013 directory thus: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/lib, then add .dll file under C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/bin and then add .dll file again under C:/Windows/System32

Comment: @Juniar: That's not going to help fix an error with not being able to find the header file, I'm afraid.

Comment: @drescherjm where is that setting...?

Comment: @Ken White The error is not specified, is it the "libusb.h" error message. Then I guess he did not include the libusb.h header file under MSVC include directory. He should specify the error.

Comment: In your project settings: C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories.

Comment: @drescherjm its working! Thanks a lot. If you'll post this as an anwser I will be more than happy to accept it.

Comment: @user1806687 What is the exact error message you are getting? It looks like its the header file error message.

Comment: @Juniar: The question (before the edit that made it more clear) says ""I tried including the `#include "libusb.h"` but it says it cant find the file.". The edit clarifies that the error is in fact the include file. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you did not add the folder containing the header file `libusb.h` to the include folders for your compiler. As a result the compiler can not find `libusb.h` since it is not in any of the folders the compiler searches.

In Visual Studio to add a folder to the include directories open the project properties for your target and add the folder to the C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories setting.